# How to enable Soft keys on Xiaomi Redmi 1S?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, xiaomi, softkey

How to enable Nexus 5 like soft keys(navigation keys on touch screen) on android devices? My device is Xiaomi Redmi 1S running Kitkat OS. And, can it be done without rooting my phone?

Comment: Your device probably be using MIUI and I've never touched it in my life. However, in my Cyanogenmod I can enable/disable navigation bar (softkeys) through "Settings -> Buttons -> turn slider for on/off". See if you've such option.

Comment: You do mean soft keys, right?

Comment: yes.. home, back, recent buttons on screen itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please check user manual [Xiaomi Redmi 1S](https://www.manualdevices.com/xiaomi-redmi-3s-specification-and-user-manual/) but based on my experience, you have to rooting your phone and install - check this [site](http://en.miui.com/thread-27163-1-1.html). download those softkeys collection from there. but make sure rooting your phone first just as we mentioned before. Dont forget to backup your data.